# what does this javascript on keeping score for quiz mean?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about this code. It is supposed to keep score of a quiz.

```
function point() {
var questions = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var value_list = [];
var point = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    value_list.push(questions[i].value);
    if (questions[i].checked) {
        point += Number(value_list[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: I just dont quite understand this code. Can someone explain how this code works to me step by step?

Comment: can you be a bit more clear on the question. what exactly do you think it does?

Answer (score 1):

```
var questions = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Get all elements that have the tag `<input>`.`questions` is an array of all those elements.

```
var value_list = [];
var point = 0;
```

Initialize an array and a variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
```

For all the input elements in the `questions` array do the following.

```
value_list.push(questions[i].value);
```

1) Push the value of the input element into the value_list array.

```
if (questions[i].checked) {
    point += Number(value_list[i])
}
```

2) If the input is checked then add the point.The function `Number` will convert the value in `value_list[i]` to a number and then add it the points.we pass the value of the checked input tag as argument to the function.

The input in this case is a checkbox which has attributes checked and value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Line1:**

```
var questions = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

There are be elements with tag input in your HTML file.So you are taking those elements array using `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` and assigning in to variable questions.
**So outcome of this line is you will get a variable questions which will hold all input elements of your HTML document**.

**Line2:**

```
var value_list = [];
```

**This line is being used to define an array variable `value_list` and assigning empty array to it.**

**Line3:**

```
var point = 0;
```

Initializing variable `point` with value `0`.

**Line4 till end:**

```
// for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) =>for loop   syntax will iterate till the length of questions(Which is array of input elements")
```

Suppose you have two input tag elements it will iterate 2 times.

```
//  value_list.push(questions[i].value);=>taking value of ith input    element and pushing to "**value_list**" array variable
//  if (questions[i].checked) { =>  
// { checking if ith element is checked}
      point += Number(value_list[i])=>
//{ converting to munber and adding to point variable.
//  }
//}
```

**The result of this code will be the sum of all the values input tags have.
suppose you have an html file like below:**

```
<html><input type="checkbox" value="10">
  <input type="checkbox" value="20">
</html>
```

Note that only input type of checkbox has the attribute checked.After this code will successfully executed the point will be `0 + 10 + 20`.
point will hold `value` = `30`.

Best Regards,
Priyanka

Answer (score 1):

```
// We define a new function, named point. In this case, it doesn't receive any parameters.
function point() {

    // We get all the input elements, and we store it in the variable 'questions' 
    var questions = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    // We are creating a new empty list
    var value_list = [];

    // We declare a variable initialized at 0
    var point = 0;

    // we are going to loop over the items inside questions (all the input elements)
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

        // We get the value of the questions of the current iteration (questions[i].value) and we store it inside the empty list
        value_list.push(questions[i].value);

        // If the input is checked...
        if (questions[i].checked) {

            // we increment the value of point with the value in value_list[i], in this case it should be the same as questions[i],
            // because previously we store questions[i] inside value_list 
            point += Number(value_list[i])
    }
}
```

You are simply looping over all the input, and if the input it's checked, you increment the `point` variable with it's value. It could be simplified in this code

```
// We define a new function, named point. In this case, it doesn't receive any parameters.
function point() {

    // We get all the input elements, and we store it in the variable 'questions' 
    var questions = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    // We declare a variable initialized at 0
    var point = 0;

    // we are going to loop over the items inside questions (all the input elements)
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

        if (questions[i].checked) {

            point += Number(questions[i].value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function point() {
    var questions = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    //This line gets all the input tags on your page. Instead you can give all your questions a common class and do this to get count

    document.getElementsByClass("className");  
    var value_list = []; //creates an empty array value_list.
    var point = 0; //intializes a variable called point = 0 for keeping the count.
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) { 
    //Runs a for loop starting from 0 to number of questions on your screen less 1. So if you have 5 input tags this loop will run from 0 to 4.

    value_list.push(questions[i].value); //pushes the values of the questions into the array value_list.

    if (questions[i].checked) { //If questions have checked property then the point variable is trying to store a number.
        point += Number(value_list[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function point() {

var questions = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

The getElementsByTagName() method accesses all elements with the specified tagname.

```
var value_list = [];
```

Above line creates the empty list having name value_list.

```
var point = 0;
```

Set the variable point=0; Purpose of this variable is storing final result.

```
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    #var i = 0 => sets a variable before the loop starts (var i = 0).
    #i < questions.length => defines the condition for the loop to run (i must be less than question.length). questions.length calculate total number of question.
    #i++ => increases a value (i++) each time the code block in the loop has been executed.

value_list.push(questions[i].value);
```

The push() method adds new items to the end of an array.

```
    if (questions[i].checked) {
        point += Number(value_list[i])
        #Here point = point+ Number(value_list[i]), it means adds the new score
    }
}
```